# SharePoint 2019 - MSSQL 2019 configuration to protect DB's (Basic Availability Groups)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, 2019

I'm searching for advise with SharePoint database when using Always On availability group.

I have MSSQL server with 2019 Standard version and SharePoint 2019 Standard license.
I wanna protect my DBs by availability groups.

I was searching but I couldn't find one official or integrate answer for question's.

How can I use basic availability groups on MSSQL to protect SharePoint databases? Is it supported solution by Microsoft? This solution (BAG) has any risk in usage?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is good idea, as it has limitation of the only 1 database in the availability group. Their are limitation in SharePoint powershell commands, where you need multiple databases in the same group i.e Config/ admin. search service.

You can read this thread for more information:
[SharePoint and Always On Basic Availability Groups?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32fc3ac9-e0d9-4cf7-86b5-2e671d68b5c8/sharepoint-and-always-on-basic-availability-groups?forum=SP2016)

Answer (score 0):

As Basic AGs can only protect a single database, it isn't very useful for SharePoint.

While Mirroring has been deprecated for quite a few versions but has yet to be removed.

SQL Enterprise with AlwaysOn Availability Groups would be the modern method of synchronization.

Comment: You have right, i know this but this is only option for me and that i ask here. I was hoping that somebody made this configuration and could help me.

Comment: No, because Basic AGs just aren't fit for use or really compatible with SharePoint given it has a minimum of two databases (Config an Admin).